# How to loop the 3rd uri segment numerical value in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, loops, for-loop, uri

What I want to do is to display something like this in one view:

```
/project_name/index.php/controller/controller_function/1
/project_name/index.php/controller/controller_function/2
/project_name/index.php/controller/controller_function/3
```

and up to

```
/project_name/index.php/controller/controller_function/n
```

Each link will be appended / concatenated.

Is this possible? If yes can you please show an example?

Comment: Not sure that i understand your question, but - you can simple make for loop in view? Is that number ID field of database record, or something else?

Comment: @nevermind I made a custom action for the table using the grocery crud. Instead of clicking individually to view the processed data, 

Click: view processed data for person1
Click: view processed data for person2 and so on

what to do is
Click: view processed data for person1 and view processed data for person2

numberID field is from the database by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand, you want a for loop with 3rd parameter as limit. Is that what you want? If not, please explain better, maybe a some code or context.

```
$value = $this->uri->segment(3);

for ($i=0; $i < $value; $i++){
echo site_url('controller/controller_function/'. ($i + 1));
}
```